# golang - exec.Command start a process and get pid

Tags: linux, go

I wrote a function to run process, this is my code:

```
func execCmd(user User, command string) (*exec.Cmd, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Getenv("SHELL"), "-c", command)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{}
    cmd.SysProcAttr.Credential = &syscall.Credential{Uid: uint32(user.UID), Gid: uint32(user.GID)}
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return cmd, nil
}
```

I used `cmd.Process.Pid` to get the pid of the process after the process has started.
It works well with a command like `/tmp/test` but returns an unexpected pid with the command `/tmp/test > /tmp/test.log`. The command returns 1 less than the actual pid (`actual pid - 1`). I want to get the pid `/tmp/test` and after use this pid kill `/tmp/test`.

For example: `cmd.Process.pid = 10667`, but `ps -ef | grep /tmp/test` shows that the pid equals 10668

Thanks.

Comment: `/tmp/test > /tmp/test.log` makes two process, whos pid you need?

Comment: As @JiangYD says, you're getting the PID of the shell, not the command**s** that the shell runs. Also note that this is unsafe as `SHELL` may be set to anything, perhaps a shell with different/unexpected escaping/semantics (e.g. it may not implement `-c`). It's especially dangerous if the input `command string` is not per-screened/verified as safe (e.g. `execCmd(toUser("root"), "rm -rf / & expected_cmd")`.

Comment: @JiangYD   i need the process `/tmp/test` , i want to use the pid to kill process `/tmp/test`